# Can I use Project Atlas just before the Runner accesses cards from HQ?

Tags: android-netrunner

Project Atlas is a Corporation agenda that can be over-advanced to provide agenda counters for the following ability:

> Hosted agenda counter: Search R&D for 1 card, reveal it, and add it to HQ. Shuffle R&D.

Because it has no [Click] requirement, I understand that I can use this ability during the Runner's turn.

Imagine that I have a scored Project Atlas with a counter on it and the Runner runs on HQ. They pass the last ICE. **Before the Runner accesses HQ, can I use this ability to fetch (say) a Snare into my HQ?**

If so, must I do it before they choose to access (so that they could see me add the card and then jack out without accessing)? Or can I do it after they confirm that they want to access a card, giving them no opportunity to jack out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading the FAQ ([here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf)), specifically the section on the timing of a run, I believe I can now answer my own question. The relevant steps read:

> 4 The Runner APPROACHES the attacked server.
>
> > 4.1 [Paid abilities]
> >
> > 4.2 The Runner decides whether to continue the run.
> >         ...Either the Runner JACKS OUT: [end the run unsuccessfully]
> >         ...Or the Runner continues the run: go to 4.3.
> >
> > 4.3 [Paid abilities and non-ice can be rezzed]
> >
> > 4.4 The run is considered to be successful. (‘When successful’ conditionals meet their trigger conditions)
> >
> > 4.5 Access cards, then [end the run].

Based on these clarifications, **you may use the ability before or after the Runner decides if they'd like to access.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use paid abilities at any point in the timing diagram with the symbol for using paid abilities. There is an option after runner chooses weather to Jack-out or continue to access the server where you can do this. The runner will then have to access your HQ, unless he has used something like Account Siphon.